# How to express a Poisson regression equation as a quasi-Poisson

Tags: poissons-equation

I was reading this paper: http://www.researchgate.net/publication/13878515_A_simple_non-linear_model_in_incidence_prediction

and was wondering whether the equations 1 and 3 presented in the paper to represent modeling of cancer incidence using a Poisson distribution could be converted into a quasi-Poission model. Is this possible? How would the formulae below look if they follow a quasi-Poisson model instead?

$ln(EM_{it}) = \alpha_i + \beta t$

$EM_{it} = \alpha_i(1 + \beta t)$

where $i$ is age group and $t$ period, $EM_{it}$ is the expected incidence rate, $\beta$ is a drift parameter and $\alpha_i$ is the baseline incidence rate.

NOTE: the journal requires a subscription but is not necessary to access since I have put the two relevant equations above.

NOTE: I originally posted this question on stats.stackexchange.com but in retrospect I think that this is the correct forum for such a question (I'll remove the stats.stackexchange.com question unless I get an answer for the bounty set).